# Is it possible to pass data from JavaScript to php file with post method, without using AJAX and From Submit

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

I am using local Storage and now I want to send that data to a PHP file, but I want to send it without AJAX, because in AJAX what ever I echo in the target PHP file it comes back, and I have to display a separate form in that PHP.

And also without using get Method.

So I can get the data by just using `$_POST[]` method in the PHP file.

Comment: Yes you can.. what did you tried???

Comment: Without sending an AJAX request, or using some other asynchronous communication method like websockets, you'd need to actually interrupt the user to send the info (eg: submit a form).

Comment: You do know that you don't _have_ to show the response in an Ajax call? You can still make the request and then  just ignore the response.

Comment: afaik there are several hacks to send data as a `GET` request to some server, without using forms or ajax. But I don't know any other way to send a `POST`; well a socket could do this, but that's more complicated/fiddly.

Comment: I should clarify my comment. That applies only if the `POST` http method is a requirement.

Comment: $.post(url, {
   'key': variable
  },
  function (respons) {}